# VBA string array

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

```
 Dim j as integer
 Dim b as integer
 Dim arrayMaterial as string
 Dim array1()
 For j=1 to numrows-1
     For i = 1 To 3
       ReDim Preserve array1(0 To 3,  0 To numrows)
       array1(i, j) = Cells(j + 1, i + 6)
     Next
 Next
    For j = 1 To numrows - 1
      For b = 1 To 3
          arrayMaterial = array1(b, j)
      Next
    MsgBox Join(arrayMaterial, " ")
```

I want to be able to store the array values into a combined string. I keep getting an error message. Any suggestions?

Comment: Not quite shure of what you want to achieve. This maybe? `arrayMaterial = arrayMaterial & " " & array1(b, j)`. And after that `MsgBox arrayMaterial`.

Comment: It might be helpful if you posted the error message and explained your desired outcome.

Comment: @aggieman Does Vityata answer or my comment help to solve your problem? Politeness will cause no harm...

Comment: yes, thanks for the help. I was able to figure something out from all the comments

Answer (score 0):

No clue what you are trying to do. You miss one next and the variables are not defined. And arraymaterial is a string, not an array. Anyhow, if you want to put a bidimensional array in the msgbox, this is a good way to do it with your code :

```
Option Explicit
Sub TestMe()
    Dim j As Long
    Dim b As Long
    Dim arrayMaterial As String
    Dim numrows As Long: numrows = 5
    Dim i As Long

    Dim array1() As Long

    For j = 1 To numrows - 1
        For i = 1 To 3
            ReDim Preserve array1(0 To 3, 0 To numrows)
            array1(i, j) = Cells(j + 1, i + 6)

        Next i
    Next j
    MsgBox WriteArrayToImmediateWindow(array1)
End Sub

'taken from SO and modified a bit
Function WriteArrayToImmediateWindow(arrSubA As Variant) As String

    Dim rowString As String
    Dim iSubA As Long
    Dim jSubA As Long

    rowString = ""

    For iSubA = 1 To UBound(arrSubA, 1)
        rowString = arrSubA(iSubA, 1)
        For jSubA = 2 To UBound(arrSubA, 2)
            rowString = rowString & "," & arrSubA(iSubA, jSubA)
        Next jSubA
        WriteArrayToImmediateWindow = WriteArrayToImmediateWindow & vbCrLf & rowString
    Next iSubA

End Function
```